# Don't understand cause of this KeyError when importing module

Tags: python, module, spyder

I am new to creating modules in Python, and I want to create a module and export the results. I have the following so far and I named the module `Card_module`:

```
from random import shuffle

def Cards(deck,colour):
    for item in colour:
        return (item,deck)

def Vdeckk():
    colour=['RED', 'YELLOW', 'BLACK']
    deck=[]
    deck=[Cards(value,colour)for value in range(1,11)]
    return (deck)

if __name__=='__main__':
    Vdeckk()
```

When I run `import Card_module` then `Card_module.Vdeckk()` I receive the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-61-8a304a818b2c>", line 1, in <module>
    Card_module.Vdeckk()
  File "C:\Users\mnazari\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\displayhook.py", line 258, in __call__
    self.update_user_ns(result)
  File "C:\Users\mnazari\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\displayhook.py", line 196, in update_user_ns
    if result is not self.shell.user_ns['_oh']:
KeyError: '_oh'
```

Comment: None of those error messages would come from the code you posted.

Comment: The error you received is related to Ipython not your code. Try run your code in a standard python interpreter and see if you get the error.

Comment: I run your code on my Ipython console and everything was ok. You shoud try an other interpreter maybe.

Comment: what exactly did you run that gets that error?  were you running a `.py` file or were you executing commands from an interpreter?  If you were running from a file, can you please put the file here?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) This looks like an installation issue. My advice is for you to uninstall and reinstall Anaconda or create a conda env and test things again. That should fix your problem.

Comment: thank you everyone, definitely seems to be an issue with the specific install, it works now after using a different console.